# symlinked udev rule not working upon OS boot

Tags: symlink, udev

I have a `udev` rule that mounts a certain USB device to a custom mount point under `/media` I confirm working, and it sits on my user's space (say `/home/myuser/a.rules`). And I created a symbolic link from say `/etc/udev/rules.d/52-link-a.rules` to it. Now, OS starts then it seems to fail mounting to that particular point, and instead mounts to something generic `/media/myuser/CMSTICKM`, and I see nautilus pops up with the folder in the USB opened.

I was able to fix this by stopping symlink and instead copy the udev rule in the same `/etc/udev/rules.d/`. I can only assume but when Ubuntu boots, symbolic linking occurs before `systemd-udevd` starts, thus the linked custom udev rule is not read then mount fails, but not entirely sure. Could some one explain why?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
```

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this problem too.  I suspect that udev loads so early in the boot process that only the root partition is available, before `/home` has been mounted.  So when udev loads, your symlinks appear broken as the target files do not yet exist.

I guess one solution is to reload the udev config after the partition has mounted, but this won't apply any new rules to hardware that has already been detected.

The best solution (if you need the rules to apply to hardware that's present during boot) is probably to figure out some other way of applying the rules, such as using rsync to copy them into `/etc/udev/rules.d/` and forgetting the symlinks.